# Nginx how to host different sites to the same domain but on different ports

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have two laravel A and B projects on the ubuntu server. My IP:80 opens up A site. I want site B to open as well on IP:{port}. Is it possible using Nginx?
What I have tried so far is creating another config file in sites-available:

```
server {
  listen 777;
  root /var/www/B/public;
  ..
}
```

But it is not opening site B. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ports can listen on the same `server` block. Consider listening on IP6 too with `[::]:`

```
server {
  listen      80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen      777;
  listen [::]:777;

  server_name a.example.com
              b.example.com;
  ...
}
```

Or use 2 server blocks if using different roots. The [`include`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) directive can contain common configuration to both blocks:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name   a.example.com;
  root /var/www/a.example.com;
  include conf.d/includes/common.conf;
}

server {
  listen      777;
  listen [::]:777;

  server_name   b.example.com;
  root /var/www/b.example.com;
  include conf.d/includes/common.conf;
}
```

Test with curl to avoid browser caching:

```
$ curl -I http://example.com:80/
$ curl -I http://example.com:777/
```

Comment: But how to differentiate between two different project folders.. in same server block.